# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns has strange column size for int value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a PostgreSQL table

```
create table test (
id int,
name varchar(2),
active boolean,
long_id bigint,
created timestamptz);
)
```

I want to get name, type and size of each column in this table. This is my code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test", "postgres", "123");
        final DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        try (final ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getColumns("public", null, "test", null)) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME") + " " + resultSet.getInt("DATA_TYPE") + " " + resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE"));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output

```
id 4 10
name 12 2
active -7 1
long_id -5 19
created 93 35
```

The third column shows column size, for example for boolean value **active** it's 1 byte. But why does it show 10 bytes for **id** value (which is int in PostgreSQL) instead of 4?

Comment: Why does your question have `ResultSetMetaData` in its title, when your question is about the result set of `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (emphasis mine):

> The COLUMN_SIZE column specifies the column size for the given column.
>   **For numeric data, this is the maximum precision.** For character data, this is the length in characters. For datetime datatypes, this
>   is the length in characters of the String representation (assuming the
>   maximum allowed precision of the fractional seconds component). For
>   binary data, this is the length in bytes. For the ROWID datatype, this
>   is the length in bytes. Null is returned for data types where the
>   column size is not applicable.

The maximum precision of a 32 bit integer is 10, the maximum precision of a 64 bit integer (long) is 19.

In other words, your assumption that `COLUMN_SIZE` contains the size in bytes is wrong. The `getColumns` result doesn't provide that information, except for character types in column `CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH`.

The definition of `COLUMN_SIZE` is derived from the X/Open SQL CLI, which in modified form lives on in the Call-Level Interface (SQL/CLI) standard (ISO-9075-3), specifically from the `DescribeCol` function (quoted from a draft of ISO-9075-3:2003):

> b) Case:
>     i) If the data type of C is character string, then ColumnSize is set to the maximum length in octets of C.
>     ii) If the data type of C is exact numeric or approximate numeric, then ColumnSize is set to the maximum length of C in decimal digits.
>     iii) If the data type of C is datetime or interval, then ColumnSize is set to the length in positions of C.
>     iv) If the data type of C is a reference type, then ColumnSize is set to the length in octets of that reference type.
>     v) Otherwise, ColumnSize is set to an implementation-dependent value.